# suppose that seven balls are selected at random without replacement

Tags: probability

suppose that seven balls are selected at random without replacement from a box containing five red and ten blue balls. If Y denotes the proportion of red balls in the sample, what are the mean and the variance of Y?

Comment: What have you done?  Any thoughts?  For the mean, linearity of expectation.

Comment: used hypergeometric distribution formulas, but its not giving me the right answer, I can't seem to find the proper formula to get the right answer... Var(Y) = ((n*A*B)/((A+B)^2))*((A+B-n)/(A+B-1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ denote the number of red balls among seven balls, then $0\leq n\leq 5$,

Use the fact $n$ follows hyper geometric distribution, calculate mean and variance for $n$ [by formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with $n=7,k=5,N=15$, we have $$E(n)=\frac{5\times 7}{15}, Var(n)=7\frac{5}{15}\frac{10}{15}\frac{15-7}{15-1}$$ 
Then use $Y=\frac{n}{7}$ we have $$E(Y)=\frac{E(n)}{7}=\frac{1}{3}, Var(Y)=\frac{Var(n)}{49}=0.018$$.

Comment: so I've tried both ways that you presented and neither resulted in the answer, I assume I'm doing it wrong choices i have are a) 0.426 and 0.025, b) 0.333 and 0.018, c) 0.149 and 0.278, d) 0.798 and 0.020... I need the answer, I want to know how to do it though

Comment: @NoobCoder85 it should be b)